# Showing the correctness of inequality with $e$

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, inequality

Is true that always for every $x$ and $n, n\not=0$ this inequality is true:
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{x} \leq e^{-x/n}\;\;?$$

I have the doubt about the values of $n$ which are very close to $0$, but I don't know how to prove it or show counterexample that this inequality is wrong?

Comment: *the values of n which are very close to 0*: isn't $n$ assumed to be a positive integer? Not that it would change anything.

Comment: @Siméon Oh, yes you are right!

Comment: Actually, n being a positive integer is critical. For example, try n=0.5, x=2.

Answer (score 2):

The function $f\colon t\mapsto \log(1-t)$ is concave $\left(f''(t)=\frac{-1}{(1-t)^2}\right)$ so the curve of $f$ is below its tangent line at the point $t=0$ with equation $y=-t$ hence
$$\log(1-t)\le -t\quad \forall t<1$$
hence we have
$$\log\left(1-\frac 1 n\right)\le -\frac 1 n$$
now multiply by $x\ge0$ and apply the exponantial function you get the result.